# "Show Holidays Calendar" in Calendar.app (Mac) does not

Tags: macos, mac, calendar

The Calendar.app in macOS Sierra and Mojave (10.14) offers a "Show Holidays calendar" checkbox in `Preferences` > `General` panel.

According to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/subscribe-to-calendars-icl1022/11.0/mac/10.14) and [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/04/show-holidays-calendar-mac-os-x/), a "US Holidays" calendar should appear. On my Mac nothing happens when checking or unchecking that box.

Any suggestions on making the Holidays calendar appear?

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251256884